# Metadata.framework error while running root in jupyter

Tags: metadata, jupyter, root-framework

I am running a code in jupyter notebook (here is the code for reference):

```
import ROOT as root 

f = root.TFile("160721_0828.root")

for event in f.tree.events:
     print (1)
```

It should be a simple code, looping through a file. But when I run it, the kernel crushes and I have to restart everything. I also get in terminal many errors of this kind:

```
2016-08-08 18:25:20.439 atos[99872:272f] Metadata.framework [Error]: couldn't get the client port
 0x0000000100000cc4 in start (in python) + 52
```

before the program crushes. I am using a Mac, version 10.9.5. What could be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your Spotlight indexing is disabled and necessary metadata is inaccessible.

Try to turn Spotlight indexing <kbd>On</kbd> and the error message:

```
"Metadata.framework [Error]: couldn't get the client port"
```

disappears and kernel will be stable.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But if I turn indexing on, the whole storage on my computer goes full. There is a way to fix this without Spotlight? Or there is a way to activate Spotlight without getting my storage full?

Comment: I'm afraid not. That's the only way that I know.

Comment: Here are different Spotlight issues:

https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/29333 ,
https://community.filemaker.com/thread/144447 ,
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5537027?tstart=0